# What shouldn't (have) happen(ed)

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, tense, sentence-structure

When something bad happens to you that you could expect it to happen, but did not wish that happen, you would probably say:

> 1) Finally, that shouldn't **have happened**, happened. 
>   2) Finally, that shouldn't **happen**, happened.

**Added example:**
He is really in need these days. He can barely make a living for his family. Due to many problems that you are not aware, he got very sensitive recently. Unfortunately his temperament had affected his job too in the manner that I was worried if he loses his job! Apparently, he entered into a quarrel with his boss just yesterday! Unfortunately, his boss fired him today. Finally, what........................................

I wonder which tense sounds grammatically correct here and why?

Comment: I'm not sure if you repeated the word happen(ed) on purpose here? The correct sentence would be. Apart from that, it is just a matter of tense. Please can you provide a bit more context for these sentences?

Comment: Moderators do not have the ability to undo any automated throttling of your account’s ability to ask questions. Read the message that is presented carefully, read any links in it, and follow the instructions. If the instructions are unclear, post a question on [meta] explaining the difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will allow me to make a few more minor tweaks at the same time:

> He is really in need these days. He can barely make a living for his family. Due to many problems, **which** you are not aware **of**, he **become** very sensitive recently. Unfortunately, his temperament had affected his job too, **to the extent that** I was worried he may **lose** his job! Apparently, he entered into a quarrel with his boss just yesterday! Unfortunately, his boss fired him today. Finally, what **shouldn't have happened, happened**.

The initial sentence you asked about had a "that" where you have a "what" above. This is what caused my confusion with the repeated word.

The reason for "have" is because you are talking in past tense I think.

Comment: One more question @Bee. What is wrong with "what shouldn't **happen**, happened"?

Comment: As I mentioned, this is just to do with tenses. In another scenario, that would be grammatically correct. If you were talking about something that could happen again, you might use happen instead. E.g. He was racially abused. What shouldn't happen, happened.

Comment: Just another note on tense: "he **become** very sensitive recently"  should be either "he **became**" or more likely, "he **has become**" (past or present perfect)